# 1and1 hosting asp.net mvc 2 server error in '/' application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, web-config, server-error

I am having a problem with a small website that I am creating in visual studio 2008, using asp.net mvc 2, and the hosting server 1and1.co.uk. I have no database within the website yet, as it is a work in progress, just need the site up and running properly.

The problem is that I even after uploading the published website to the account on 1and1, I still get the error:

"error in '/' application"

Im not too sure if it is the web.config file or not. From what I have seen on some forums and websites I can not seem to sort this problem out.

Can someone please help me out with this problem
Many thanks.

Comment: Does your site run locally ? and do ou get any line nr where the error is located ?

Comment: yes the site runs fine locally. no I dont get a line. its saying its in the web.config file. below is what I am getting, but from what I have researched before coming on here, I can not find a full answer/tutorial.

Comment: '<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>'

Comment: is mvc 2 installed on the hosting? and tr setting r config to customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"

Comment: to be honest im not too sure, my friend set up the account with 1and1.co.uk before I knew about it. And im not too sure if it is installed on the hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then its better to find out what you can run on your hosting, try first to run an empty web application without mvc and see if it runs.

Comment: done that, an empty asp.net website works fine. Im guessing the problem is that the hosting does not support MVC 2?

Comment: yes that's possible, do you have the option to install it through yr control panel? if not, contact yr hosting and ask them if its possible, and if that is not possible then i think you need another hosting hat can handle mvc

Comment: okay will try and find out the information, and see if I can either install it myself or if the hosting can. thank you for you help Johnn, I will report back on here to let you know what I will have done

Comment: Hi john, forgot about this. My friend just had windows hosting so I had to change a few things around and just normal asp.net